# GPU not available in Spyder

Tags: gpu, nvidia, spyder, shutdown, pytorch

A python program (PyTorch, via Spyder, running two GPUs) was running smoothly and using the two GPUs. Liunx-Ubunto-16.04 went suspended, due to locking the screen; then after log-ing, Spyder detected 0 GPUs. The GPUs, nonetheless, were available at the terminal ($ nvidia-smi). I had to restart the computer to get the GPUs back into Spyder.

Maybe there is a better way to initialize the GPUs, aside from managing the power settings, as the GPUs might be toggled off for other reasons.

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
Out[4]: False
```

Comment: If PyTorch needs some environment variables to detect your GPUs, you need to start Spyder from a terminal (e.g. xterm or konsole).

Comment: I am launching it from Anaconda. Even after restarting Anaconda, then restarting Spyder, the problem was not resolved. 
If starting from a terminal would solve the problem, this means there is a problem with Anaconda. No?